# How to make pointer cursor in span tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my cursor is displaying as an arrow when hovered. How to change the cursor to a pointer when hovered for both icons as in the image below?

The code for css: `style='cursor:pointer'` in my span tag is not working.

[image]

```js
$("#actionTable").DataTable({
  columns: [{
    "data": "filename",
    "className": "text-center",
    render: function(data) {
      return "<span title='view' onclick='view_file(&quot;" + data + "&quot;)'><img src='images/view_file.png' style='cursor:pointer'></span><span title='delete' onclick='delete_file(&quot;" + data + "&quot;)'><img src='images/bin.png' style='cursor:pointer'></span>";
    }
  }],
});
```

Comment: `style='cursor:pointer'` should work. Give style to span instead of image and check.

Comment: Try inspect your code and look if the style='cursor:pointer' is there

Comment: Try add !import in style.

Comment: @egvrcn I think you mean `!important`, but that's a) bad practice and b) redundant on an inline style.